# Check if a file exists faster than OPEN DATASET

Tags: performance, abap

I'm searching for a way to check if a file exists *before* using the OPEN DATASET command to open it. The OPEN DATASET command takes up to 30 seconds to trigger an exception, which is too slow for my liking.

This is the code:

```
TRY.
  OPEN DATASET lv_file FOR OUTPUT IN TEXT MODE
                       ENCODING DEFAULT
                       WITH SMART LINEFEED.

  CONCATENATE ` ` lv_resultdata INTO lv_resultdata.

  TRANSFER lv_resultdata TO lv_file.
  CLOSE DATASET lv_file.

CATCH cx_sy_file_access_error.

MESSAGE 'Placeholder-message. File cannot be reached'.
EXIT.
ENDTRY.
```

Comment: 30 seconds to notice that the file you are trying to open does not exist? Are you accessing the file from a network share? In that case any other method will likely have to go through the same bottleneck.

Comment: @Philipp the files are on a different server, but I don't think the network is the bottleneck.  It's much faster (less than a second) when the file is actually there. The fact that it's almost exactly 30 seconds leads me to believe that there is a timeout limit within the OPEN DATASET command.

Comment: ...or a timeout limit in the implementation of your operating system of whatever protocol you use to access files via network.

Comment: Try by executing an OS command (`SM49` and SXPG* function modules).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DATA: filepath TYPE epsf-epsdirnam VALUE '/tmp'.

CALL FUNCTION 'EPS_GET_DIRECTORY_LISTING'
  EXPORTING
    dir_name               = filepath
    file_mask              = 'somefile.txt'
  EXCEPTIONS
    invalid_eps_subdir     = 1
    sapgparam_failed       = 2
    build_directory_failed = 3
    no_authorization       = 4
    read_directory_failed  = 5
    too_many_read_errors   = 6
    empty_directory_list   = 7
    OTHERS                 = 8.

CHECK sy-subrc = 0.

" writing dataset
```

It can also be used for remote servers.